# NSCLIENT\NRPE doesnt handle arguments with white spaces

Tags: nagios, nrpe, nsclient++

I have a short script that prints out an argument being sent to it.

Suppose I send over "print this",
no matter what I do it always prints out only "print".
I have tried with either powershell or batch - same result.
I also tried in Test Mode and it's the exact same issue.

Has anyone ever came across this?

Comment: Have you [seen this FAQ](https://www.nsclient.org/nscp/wiki/FAQ#a5.HowdoIproperlyescapespacesinstrings)? Also, it may be easier to assist if you provide some of your script, in particular the section which is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my problem, I forgot to add double quotes to the arguments IN the NSCLIENT itself. *FACE PALM*

Just for a reference:

```
test = cmd /c echo scripts\\test.ps1 $ARG1$; exit($lastexitcode) | powershell.exe -command -
```

Should be:

```
test = cmd /c echo scripts\\test.ps1 "$ARG1$"; exit($lastexitcode) | powershell.exe -command -
```